# How to add HTML on Opencart?

Tags: opencart

I am asking this for a friend that uses Opencart. I wasn't able to find that myself.

Basically he just wants open a custom checkout instead of Paypal.

Comment: In OC are HTML module where you can add your html. Extensions/Extensions and from dropdown choose Modules. There you'll finde HTML module.

Comment: Are you asking to create a new html page that can be loaded instead of paypal

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your add HTML on opencart

You have to do two steps

Step No 1 .

Enable HTML Module through 
Extensions > Module > HTML Module
You will get Text Editor. Where you can work on your HTML Code. Make sure its valid one.

Step No 2

Place your HTML Module

Design > Layouts

You can place HTML any one of your page.

Hope you got it.

Comment: the same answer as I have add comment